# How to disable AVS check in commerce cybersource SASOP

Tags: 7, commerce

Using [Commerce CyberSource SASOP](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_cybersource_sasop) it is possible to ignore the results of AVS verification? 
There is an option for this as specified in the CyberSource [Development Guide](http://apps.cybersource.com/library/documentation/dev_guides/Secure_Acceptance_SOP/Secure_Acceptance_SOP.pdf) on the page 74.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to add parameters to the data using `hook_commerce_cybersource_sasop_transaction_data_alter($data)`

```
<?php
my_module_commerce_cybersource_sasop_transaction_data_alter($data) {
  // Ignore AVS check
  $data['ignore_avs'] = 'true';
}
```

[Issue in Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/2425977)